# simple menu in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, menu

I have created a two level menu (see code below) and is not working correct.

I noticed that i have to enter the numbers twice to work. and the 2nd level menu does not work

I wonder if you could help.

Thank you

```
def main():

choice =''
while choice !='0':
    choice = input ('Main choice: type: \nchoice 1: \nchoice 2: \nchoice 3: \nchoice 4:  \nchoice 5: \nchoice 6: ')
    print ('main menu 0')
    if choice =='1':
        print ('choice 1 - first level')
        choice = input ('Main choice: type: \nchoice 1: \nchoice 2:\nchoice 3 to go back:')
        if choice =='1':
            print ('choice 1:1 - end level menu')
            choice = input ('Main choice: type: \nchoice 1: \nchoice 2:\nchoice 3 to go back:')
        elif choice =='2':
            print ('choice 2:1 - end level menu')
            choice = input ('Main choice: type: \nchoice 1: \nchoice 2:\nchoice 3 to go back:')
        elif choice =='3':
            break
    elif choice =='2':
        print ('choice 2- first level')
        choice = input ('Main choice: type: \nchoice 1: \nchoice 2: \nchoice 3: \nchoice 4:  \nchoice 5: \nchoice 6: ')

    elif choice =='3':
        print ('choice 3- first level')
        choice = input ('Main choice: type: \nchoice 1: \nchoice 2: \nchoice 3: \nchoice 4:  \nchoice 5: \nchoice 6: ')

    elif choice =='4':
        print ('choice 4 - first level')
        choice = input ('Main choice: type: \nchoice 1: \nchoice 2: \nchoice 3: \nchoice 4:  \nchoice 5: \nchoice 6: ')

    elif choice =='5 - first level':
        print ('choice 5')
        joice = input ('Main choice: type: \nchoice 1: \nchoice 2: \nchoice 3: \nchoice 4:  \nchoice 5: \nchoice 6: ')
```

main()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After playing with your code some, I was able to make some changes, and hopefully they will sink in. Once you define a function, you have to call it. So it is not enough to define `main` -- you have to call it in your code by doing `main()`. 

For choice 5, you wanted an option to go to a second menu. So I defined another function and called it `second_menu()`. I printed something unique so you could know that you went to the menu. The only problem is that the loop breaks, but that is fixable, if you intend the user to stay in the loop. Have a look at the new code:

```
def main():

choice ='0'
while choice =='0':
    print("Main Choice: Choose 1 of 5 choices")
    print("Choose 1 for something")
    print("Choose 2 for something")
    print("Choose 3 for something")
    print("Choose 4 for something")
    print("Choose 5 to go to another menu")

    choice = input ("Please make a choice: ")

    if choice == "5":
        print("Go to another menu")
        second_menu()
    elif choice == "4":
        print("Do Something 4")
    elif choice == "3":
        print("Do Something 3")
    elif choice == "2":
        print("Do Something 2")
    elif choice == "1":
        print("Do Something 1")
    else:
        print("I don't understand your choice.")

 def second_menu():
     print("This is the second menu")

 main()
```

Try copy, pasting, and running this code to see if it is closer to what you were wanting. Also, take time to notice how the `if/elif/else` logic works. Let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: I like you your best. However when you make a choice you loose the menu. Is it possible to keep the menu always present? Thank you

Comment: Just add "while True:" above "choice = '0'" and it will stay in a loop. I am not sure why you would want to do this, but it would accomplish the goal. Also, if you like the answer I have provided you, please don't forget to click the check mark next to my answer. It provides reputation for both of us.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what you are trying to accomplish with your code. I even pasted it in IDLE, and I am still not sure. No worries, though, I am here to help. I have created a few menus too. Here is an example of one of mine:

```
while loop_condition == True:
print("\nWelcome to Python Calculator!\n")
print("\nPlease enter a number for what you want to do.\n")
print("Enter 1 for addition.")
print("Enter 2 for subtaction.")
print("Enter 3 for division.")
print("Enter 4 for multiplication.")
print("Enter 5 to quit.\n")

main_input = int(input("What would you like to do? "))
```

Then I followed that with the conditional logic.

```
if main_input == 5:
    loop_condition = False
    break
else:
    num1 = int(input("\nEnter your first number: "))
    num2 = int(input("Enter your sencond number: "))


    if main_input == 1:
        print(add(num1,num2))
    elif main_input == 2:
        print(sub(num1,num2))
    elif main_input == 3:
        print(div(num1,num2))
    elif main_input == 4:
        print(multi(num1,num2))
```

By printing out the choices on a few lines, and then handling the input in a separate variable, I was able to keep the code fairly clean. Let me know if this does not address your concern, or at least help in some way.

Answer (score 0):

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Name:        menu.py
# Purpose:      Despliega un menu guardado en un diccionario
#               y ejecura la funcion correspondiente a cada entrada 
#               del diccionario
#
def hace_La_0():
    return 'hice la cero'

def hace_La_1():
    return 'hice la uno'

def hace_La_2():
    return 'hice la dos'

def hace_La_f():
    return 'hice la f. Me salgo'


def llama_la(opcion='f'):
    # Obtiene la funcion del diccionario
    func = opciones[opcion]['Funcion']
##    print(func)
##    Enter_continuar()
    # Ejecuta la function
    return func()

def cls():
    import os
    _=os.system("cls")# en windows
##    _=os.system("clear") # en unix linux
##    print ("\n" * 25) #pseudo limpiar la pantalla sin os solo la desplaza

def menu(hecho='',s=25):
    print('Estas son las opciones disponibles del programa:','\n','-'*s)
    for op in opciones:
        print('\t',op,' : ',opciones[op]['Des'])
    print('-'*s,'Ya realice->',hecho)
    op=input('Opcion--->').lower()
    if op in opciones:
        print(llama_la(opcion=op))
        if op=='f':
            return op
    else:
        print('Opcion inexistente---',op,'---intente de nuevo')
        _=imput('Enter para continuar-->')
        return ''
    return op

opciones ={
'0' : {'Des': 'La opcion 0 hace esto y lo otro y lo de mas alla', 'Funcion': hace_La_0, 'Param1':'p1','Param2' :'p2'},
'1' : {'Des': 'La opcion 1 hace esto y lo otro y lo de mas alla', 'Funcion': hace_La_1, 'Param1':'p1','Param2' :'p2'},
'2' : {'Des': 'La opcion 2 hace esto y lo otro y lo de mas alla', 'Funcion': hace_La_2, 'Param1':'p1','Param2' :'p2'},
'f' : {'Des': 'Terminar', 'Funcion': hace_La_f, 'Param1':'p1','Param2' :'p2'}
}


op,hecho,s='','',25
while op!='f':
    op=menu(hecho,s)
    hecho=hecho +' ' + op
    cls()
print('-'*s,'Fin del programa: realicé:',hecho)
```

Comment: After playing with your code some, I was able to make some changes, and hopefully they will help somebody

Answer (score 0):

The original question has been answered, but you might want to consider using [console-menu here](https://pypi.org/project/console-menu/)